# How to pass PageObject for cucumber step definition

Tags: cucumber, pageobjects, noraui

I see the following step in noraUI sources

```
@And("I expect to have {page-element} with the text {string}(\\?)")
public void expectText(Page.PageElement pageElement, String textOrKey, List<GherkinStepCondition> conditions) throws FailureException, TechnicalException {
    this.expectText(pageElement, textOrKey, new Object[0]);
}
```

I would like to use this step but I can't pass {page-element} for this step. How it should look like?

According to doc I see that it should starts with $, but this step keeps undefined from feature file

Comment: Your code need `@Conditioned` annotation

Answer (score 1):

After reading the doc I've got the solution
We still can't pass object inside of cucumber file because step will be marked as "undefined"
As it is, noraUI has it's own step parser and if I write this step inside of my feature file:
***When I click on $google.GoogleHomePage-searchButton***
This step will be defined inside of noraUi and this pageObject will be resolved from .ini file of nora configs

Comment: You can find all example on this sample: https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/test/resources/steps/hello.feature

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
@Conditioned
@And("I expect to have {page-element} with the text {string}(\\?)")
public void expectText(PageElement pageElement, String textOrKey, List<GherkinStepCondition> conditions) throws FailureException, TechnicalException {
    // code to check if the pageElement exists and if it matches the string
}
```

Comment: actually no, This steps still seems undefined if I pass my custom page element.